# link_to logic explain please

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I do:

```
<%= link_to "treatments", new_client_treatment %>
```

It's not working... why?

I also tried:

```
<%= link_to "treatments", :controller => "treatments", :action => "show" %>
```

without any results.

I got clients with treatments, every client can have more treatments.

```
class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
end
```

in the Client model

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :treatments
end
```

routes:

```
resources :clients do
        resources :treatments
    end


Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
    client_treatments GET    /clients/:client_id/treatments(.:format)          treatments#index
                      POST   /clients/:client_id/treatments(.:format)          treatments#create
 new_client_treatment GET    /clients/:client_id/treatments/new(.:format)      treatments#new
edit_client_treatment GET    /clients/:client_id/treatments/:id/edit(.:format) treatments#edit
     client_treatment GET    /clients/:client_id/treatments/:id(.:format)      treatments#show
                      PATCH  /clients/:client_id/treatments/:id(.:format)      treatments#update
                      PUT    /clients/:client_id/treatments/:id(.:format)      treatments#update
                      DELETE /clients/:client_id/treatments/:id(.:format)      treatments#destroy
              clients GET    /clients(.:format)                                clients#index
                      POST   /clients(.:format)                                clients#create
           new_client GET    /clients/new(.:format)                            clients#new
          edit_client GET    /clients/:id/edit(.:format)                       clients#edit
               client GET    /clients/:id(.:format)                            clients#show
                      PATCH  /clients/:id(.:format)                            clients#update
                      PUT    /clients/:id(.:format)                            clients#update
                      DELETE /clients/:id(.:format)                            clients#destroy
                 root GET    /                                                 index#welcome
```

Let me know if you need more information on that issue.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supposing that client object is something like

```
@client = Client.first #only for example you have to give your client object here
<%= link_to "treatments", new_client_treatment_path(@client) %>
```

the route it is looking for is

```
"/clients/:client_id/treatments/new"
```

Answer (score 0):

`new_client_treatment` is the name of the route. When you want to link to it, you have to add a `_path` to the end of it so Rails knows it's a relative path. If you would like to make it an absolute path, you add `_url` to the end of it instead of `_path`.

Thus, `<%= link_to "treatments", new_client_treatment_path %>` would fix your issue.

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"treatments", :id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:client_id] I got this error then.

Comment: The error occurs because you need to pass `:client_id` to your url helper because it routes to the resource member action. So, you need to change `new_client_treatment_path` to `new_client_treatment_path(@client)`.